# Any way to remove divs that have been scrolled past in an endless webpage to prevent slowdown

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

Are there any plugins that can remove divs that have been scrolled past in chrome to keep speed fast. On an endless page scrolling chuggs down so much it's not usable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need virtual scrollbars
Case address

https://rintoj.github.io/ngx-virtual-scroller/samples